# Arrays with methods

Tags: arrays, methods

i try to write on label an array with methods. When i try to put values of array it writes system int 32 on label,   here is the code and how can put values on label 
p.s. sorry about bad English

```
enter code here void arr_5( int[] mas5)
    {
        for (int i=0, j=5; i<10; i++, j+=5)
        {
            mas5[i] = j;
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] a = new int[10];
        arr_5 (a);
        label1.Text += a.ToString() + " ";
    }
```

Comment: Im not exactly sure what you want to do, but a.toString() wont give you the result that you are looking for. It will print the hashcode of the integer array object. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()

Answer (score 1):

That's because an array contains more than one value and in order to show it you could do something like:

```
    int[] arr_5( int[] mas5)
    {
        for (int i=0, j=5; i<10; i++, j+=5)
        {
            mas5[i] = j;
        }
    return mas5;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] a = new int[10];
        arr_5 (a);
        String label="";
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; a++)
        {   
           label= label + a +" ";
        }
        label1.Text =label;
    }
```

Please be aware that i've changed your `arr_5` to return the newly created array.

Comment: can i do it without return

Comment: Depends on your exact requirement. Do you actually need the `arr_5` method?

Comment: @AlexandreKakheli Is this Java or something else?